# AS3 Using a Loader to load a file protected by htaccess

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm attempting to load an external SWF that's hosted on a site into a local SWF file.  The external SWF is in a password-protected directory using htaccess.

Here is the code I'm currently trying to use:

```
var loaderUrlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.my-website.com/externalFlashFile.swf");
loaderUrlRequest.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + $Base64.encode("username:password")));
loaderUrlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
loaderUrlRequest.data = true;
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
addChildAt(loader, 0);
loader.load(loaderUrlRequest);
```

The file URL, username, password, and base64 encoding are all checked and correct.

However, I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error opening URL 'http://www.my-website.com/externalFlashFile.swf'
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong, or if there's a better way to go about this from a purely-flash perspective?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add an IOErrorEvent handler and share the results? Also, does the url alone work in a browser?

Comment: The url works fine in the browser using http://username:password@www.my-website.com/externalFlashFile.swf or from navigating to it and inputting the username/password.

Adding an IOErrorEvent handler to the loader didn't yield anything. The function never gets called, so I'm not sure where there error is coming from.

Comment: does your listener look like: loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handler); ?

Comment: Ah, doing that gives the following error in place of the second one:

 Error #2036: Load Never Completed. URL: http://www.my-website.com/externalFlashFile.swf

Answer (score 5):

[White whale, holy grail](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html)

> In Adobe® AIR®, content in the application security sandbox (such as content installed with the AIR application) can use any request headers, without error. **However**, for content running in Adobe AIR that is in a different security sandbox, or **for content running in Flash® Player**, using following request **headers cause a runtime error**:
>
> Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ranges, Age, Allow, Allowed, **Authorization**, Charge-To, Connect, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-Range, Cookie, Date, Delete, ETag, Expect, Get, Head, Host, If-Modified-Since, Keep-Alive, Last-Modified, Location, Max-Forwards, Options, Origin, Post, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Connection, Public, Put, Range, Referer, Request-Range, Retry-After, Server, TE, Trace, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, Upgrade, URI, User-Agent, Vary, Via, Warning, WWW-Authenticate, x-flash-version.
>
> **URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost**: Sets default user and password credentials for a selected host. ... **Only Adobe® AIR®** content running in the application security sandbox can use the URLRequestDefaults class.

So, you have but one option: load your swf from a web page of that very domain that requires authorization. You'll be through http authorization steps before swf is loaded and browser will maintain the rest.

In fact, when you try to access something behind http authorization, a server issues a http response with code=401 (unless you send Authorization header beforehand). Flash Player can do nothing about it and only AIR runtime is capable of sending Authorization header in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate from within your ActionScript application, which can be achieved by use of some static variables and methods on the [URLRequestDefaults](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html) class.

All you need to do, is add these two lines of code **before** you make the call with URLLoader:

```
URLRequestDefaults.setLoginCredentialsForHost(hostname, user, password);
URLRequestDefaults.authenticate = true;
```

You can drop the requestHeaders too (unless they have another purpose).

Comment: I'm not actually creating an AIR application.  The loader SWF is to be embedded in a C# application, and my intent is to have it load the external SWF from a secure website.

Comment: My bad. I overlooked the fact that this only works in AIR. But now that I can see what you want to do: why not make it an AIR app?

Comment: It's already a fully-developed application.  The only difference is that it currently loads the SWF from a local directory, and I'd like to move it to using this Loader/Webserver set up.

Comment: Could you not make the C# app authenticate and download the swf? Then you could load it locally.

Comment: I could, but I'm trying not to go that route. SWF files are too easy to decompile, and I don't want to get into obfuscation if I can simply find a way to load the file only into memory.

Comment: note that setting up a proxy and highjacking your request for the swf to a local, decompiled version isn't beyond reach either.